# ActiveAdmin with two Polymorphic associations not filtering properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, activeadmin, polymorphic-associations

We have a Photo model that is associated with a Tag model. The tag model is a polymorphic table that can be either a Sport or a Place.

I've setup two has many through associations for Sport and Place in the Photo model. In my active admin filter, I have:

filter :sports_id, collection: proc { Sport.order('name').all }, as: :select
  filter :places_id, collection: proc { Place.order("name").all }, as: :select

This works fine if I select a sport or a place. But if I select both sport and place, it will always return zero results. It seems that it is based on how it is joining. Here is the SQL ActiveAdmin will generate:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT count_column) 
FROM (SELECT "photos"."id" AS count_column FROM "photos" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."photo_id" = "photos"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "sports" ON "sports"."id" = "tags"."taggable_id" AND tags.taggable_type = 'Sport' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" "tags_photos_join" ON "tags_photos_join"."photo_id" = "photos"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "places" ON "places"."id" = "tags"."taggable_id" AND tags.taggable_type = 'Place' 
WHERE "photos"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "sports"."id" = 1 AND "places"."id" = 1 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

If you have both a sport and a place associated with a photo, this count will return zero no matter what based on how the joins/where statements are setup.

Here is my model setup:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tags
  has_many :sports, :through => :tags
  has_many :places, :through => :tags

end


class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :sport, foreign_key: 'taggable_id', conditions: "tags.taggable_type = 'Sport'"
  belongs_to :place, foreign_key: 'taggable_id', conditions: "tags.taggable_type = 'Place'"

end


class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tags

end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tags

end
```

Here is the output from my console:

```
    Started GET "/admin/photos?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bsports_id_eq%5D=1&q%5Bplaces_id_eq%5D=1796&commit=Filter&order=id_desc" for 192.168.2.72 at 2014-09-03 14:28:55 -0700
    Processing by Admin::PhotosController#index as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"sports_id_eq"=>"1", "places_id_eq"=>"1796"}, "commit"=>"Filter", "order"=>"id_desc"}
      AdminUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
       (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT count_column) FROM (SELECT "photos"."id" AS count_column FROM "photos" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."photo_id" = "photos"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "sports" ON "sports"."id" = "tags"."taggable_id" AND tags.taggable_type = 'Sport' LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" "tags_photos_join" ON "tags_photos_join"."photo_id" = "photos"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "places" ON "places"."id" = "tags_photos_join"."taggable_id" AND tags.taggable_type = 'Place' WHERE "photos"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "sports"."id" = 1 AND "places"."id" = 1796 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count 
      Sport Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "sports".* FROM "sports" WHERE "sports"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY name
      Place Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY name
      Rendered /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activeadmin-0.6.3/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (453.4ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 466ms (Views: 451.4ms | ActiveRecord: 7.1ms)
```

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

### UPDATE

I still haven't found a solution to this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the Tag, Photo, Sport and join models (between them) from ActiveRecord with the associations.

Comment: Just updated. Thanks for looking at this

Comment: Please post the query generating trigger, which fires the posted SQL. It would also help to have the SQL generated by the working query triggers (Sport and Post alone).

Comment: Just posted. As you can see from the SQL is that the way the joins are done, it essentially makes it impossible to have a result with both a sport_id and a place_id associated with it. As if there is 1 photo with a sport_id and place_id that I'm searching for, this query would return two rows for the same photo, one with a sport_id and place_id as null, and the second with a place_id and a sport_id as null.